# Different actions between first and second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some links, called "yt-link" (+ data attr.) and some divs with hidden youtube videos. If I click on "yt-link", the hidden div become vissible. By pressing the play button on the video, the video starts. So on, very well. If I press the "yt-link" again the div become hidden but the video dont stop. So I add a scrippt to reload this video by pressing the "yt-link". It also works.

**My problem:** the reload script fired on every click, but it should only fire on every second click, the close click. Is there a way?

Thats my div script:

```
$(function(){
    $(".yt-link").click(function(){
        var attrVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $box = $('.yt-video-wrapper[data-filter="'+attrVal+'"]');

        // slideIN/Out the content
        $box.slideToggle();
    });
})
```

And thats the YT-reload script:

```
$('.yt-link').click(function(){

       // get the iframe URL
       var url = $('.yt-video').attr('src');

       // src to null, this stops the video been playing
       $('.yt-video').attr('src', '');

       // URL back to iframe
       $('.yt-video').attr('src', url);
});
```

Optional: you know a better way to stop yt-videos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution will be is to use a close event like

```
$(function () {
    $(".yt-link").click(function () {
        var attrVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        var $box = $('.yt-video-wrapper[data-filter="' + attrVal + '"]');

        // slideIN/Out the content
        $box.slideToggle().toggleClass('open');
        if (!$box.hasClass('open')) {
            $box.trigger('video-close');
        }
    });
})

$('.yt-link').on('video-close', function () {

    // get the iframe URL
    var url = $('.yt-video').attr('src');

    // src to null, this stops the video been playing
    $('.yt-video').attr('src', '');

    // URL back to iframe
    $('.yt-video').attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Ok, looks interesting ... I will try it!